# SYSDATE inside an sql query in R

Tags: sql, r, rjdbc

I am trying to automate a code where I am pulling data for the last week and run it once in a week. How can I get the Sys.Date() inside an sql query in R.

> library('RJDBC')
>
> Tdata<- dbGetQuery(conn, "select
> roll_id,source,create_date,login from
> master_data where create_date>'2017-07-17'")

So basically i want to create condition create_date> Sys.Date()-7. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using paste (or paste0):

```
Tdata <- dbGetQuery(conn,paste0("select roll_id,source,create_date,login 
                    from master_data where create_date>'", Sys.Date()-7, "'"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to get the current date from SQL query (not R). I believe you can do this with `GETDATE()`.

Another method would be to use the `paste0()` function in R to construct your query text before passing it into `dbGetQuery()`.

It would be something like `query_txt <- paste0("select roll_id, source, create_date, login from master_data where create_date > '", Sys.Date()-7, "')"`.

Then `Tdata <- dbGetQuery(conn, query_txt)`.

Hope that helps!